# Android ViewGroup add child on top of all drawings

Tags: android, android-view, viewgroup

I have a custom `ViewGroup` where I am overriding it's `dispatchDraw` and drawing some extra `Path`s which looks like this :

```
@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    mRegions.clear();
    canvas.drawPicture(mPicture);
    if (drawShader) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mShader, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
        if (mIndex != -1 && mIndex == i) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
            drawPaths(canvas, mPaths.get(i));
            canvas.clipPath(mPaths.get(i), Region.Op.INTERSECT);
            canvas.drawColor(mOverlayColor);
            Rect f = mRegions.get(i).getBounds();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawCircle(f.centerX() - mRadius, f.centerY() - mRadius, mRadius, mPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        } else {
            drawPaths(canvas, mPaths.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the things which I want is to add a child which will be placed above these things drawn on `dispatchDraw`. For now I am doing this :

```
    mBalloon = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.map_balloon, null);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(500, 150);
    mBalloon.setLayoutParams(params);
    addView(mBalloon);
    bringChildToFront(getChildAt(0));
```

in my `init()` method which is called in my `ViewGroup`'s constructor and the result is that drawing in `dispatchDraw` are placed above `mBalloon`.

Any idea how can I place my `View - mBalloon` above the things from `dispatchDraw`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to call drawChild after your custom drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the general idea of what you're trying to achieve and I'll try to suggest a different approach.

from the docs: `A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views containers.`

So a ViewGroup is not supposed to be drawing stuff on the screen at all. It is possible to do it? Yes, but it just makes your OO structure less properly done.

So my suggestion is to use whatever ViewGroup you prefer FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. And migrate the path draw code to a custom View that will draw all those paths in the screen, and in the standard ViewGroup you just have to position the custom View accordingly. probably something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView/> // just an example
    <ImageView/> // just an example

    <CustomPathView/> // your custom view

    <FrameLayout/>  // in this frame you can put views to be on top
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The things which I did it like this is just because I need to update `mBalloon`'s position depending on the selected path and move it around when I am moving paths in my `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I understand and there's always ways your CustomChild can receive callbacks from a CustomViewGroups (that do not draw anything) with interfaces etc. Other option is that all the childViews are draw during that `super.dispatchDraw`, so you would have to check the source code for that and re-implement it yourself.

Comment: here on line 2876 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java

Comment: Calling `drawChild()`, or `super.dispatchDraw()` after all drawings almost did the trick, but not as I wanted. So changing my `ViewGroup` to `View`, adding it to `RelativeLayout` and creating connection between `Fragment` which holds my `View` via `interface` did the trick, so thank you @Budius for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

For drawing childs above your extra `Path` you should call `super.dispatchDraw(canvas)` after drawing `Path`.

```
@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    mRegions.clear();
    canvas.drawPicture(mPicture);
    if (drawShader) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mShader, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
        if (mIndex != -1 && mIndex == i) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
            drawPaths(canvas, mPaths.get(i));
            canvas.clipPath(mPaths.get(i), Region.Op.INTERSECT);
            canvas.drawColor(mOverlayColor);
            Rect f = mRegions.get(i).getBounds();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawCircle(f.centerX() - mRadius, f.centerY() - mRadius, mRadius, mPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        } else {
            drawPaths(canvas, mPaths.get(i));
        }
    }
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```